# Preciso de ajuda pra configurar o Axios cliente de acordo com a rede Wi-FI/3G/4G

Tags: react-native, mobile, axios, expo

Estou desenvolvendo uma app em react-native usando expo, e o app funciona bem no Wi-Fi daqui, porém ela deve funcionar tambem fora daqui, e temos um porta no firewall que aponta pra API em nodejs pelo nosso ip publico. Não sei se fui claro mas basicamente:

No Wi-fi da Empresa o axios deve ter o attr baseUrl= 10.X.X.X
E fora do Wi-Fi ou com Wi-Fi de outro local o attr baseUrl= 189.X.X.X

É sim a app precisa ficar aqui, pensei em por tambem numa Hostgator ou GoDaddy da vida mas não vai rolar não.

Consegui pegar a conexão com Comunity/NetInfo, mas quando uso no axios ele exporta a const antes de definir o IP:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import NetInfo from "@react-native-community/netinfo"

var ip

NetInfo.addEventListener(state => {
    ip = state.type != 'wifi' ? 'http://189.X.X.X:3333' : state.details.ssid == 'WIFI_EMPRESA' ? 'http://10.X.X.X:3333' : 'http://189.X.X.X:3333'
})

const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: ip,
})

console.log(ip)


export default api
```

O resultado disso ao abrir o app e **undefined**, mas se eu salvar e atualizar ele mostra o IP, porem no primeiro momento da **'Network Error'**

Alguem saberia resolver isso, ou me dar uma solução diferente pra isso.

Att.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar definir sua instância do axios antes de adicionar o event listener, sem passar um baseURL pra ela, e na função do event listener setar a baseURL da sua instância do axios.

```
import axios from 'axios'
import NetInfo from "@react-native-community/netinfo"

var ip

const api = axios.create({})

NetInfo.addEventListener(state => {
    ip = state.type != 'wifi' ? 'http://189.X.X.X:3333' : state.details.ssid == 'WIFI_EMPRESA' ? 'http://10.X.X.X:3333' : 'http://189.X.X.X:3333'
    api.defaults.baseURL = ip
})

console.log(ip)

export default api
```

Comment: Eu tentei isso que você sugeriu mas o erro continua:

Finished building JavaScript bundle in 6160ms.

undefined
Running application on moto g(7) plus.

[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Network Error]
- node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:15:17 in createError
- node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js:80:22 in handleError

Comment: Dei uma pesquisada aqui e talvez a resposta desse problema esteja aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49798540/how-to-export-a-variable-that-takes-its-value-from-an-async-function , basicamente, vc tem que garantir que a função que define o ip seja executada antes da primeira chamada a api feita com o axios, talvez vc possa exportar essa função também e executar ela antes da chamada a api, com um await

Comment: Tentei seguir o exemplo, mas tambem n deu certo, o erro continua o mesmo.